# How to insert a UITableViewCell at the beginning of UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I am trying to set up a UITableView, with x amount of sections and X number of rows per section.

However I would like to add a single row to the top of my `UITableView` Is there is a way to hardcode this into the view?

I currently return the number of sections and rows per section based off a NSdictionary like so.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView: (UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return [letterDictionary count];

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // returns the number of rows per section based off each entry in letterDictionary   
    currentLetter = [sectionLetterArray objectAtIndex:section];
    return [[letterDictionary objectForKey:currentLetter] count];       
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a "header" to the tableview.

In your tableview class:

```
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = yourView;
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just add a row above your UItable within the table. If you just need a row of text why not use UITextField, UILabel or UITextView depending on your needs and just position it above your UItable whereever you like.

If I missunderstood you and you just like to add one row as the very first one in your first section, all you need to do sth like this:

```
if (section == 0) {
  return [[letterDictionary objectForKey:currentLetter] count]+1;
} else
{
  return [[letterDictionary objectForKey:currentLetter] count];
}
```

and ensure that when returning row for indexpath you have also a similar if-statement and return whatever you need for section == 0 and row == 0.

But this first row will certainly scroll away if you scroll down your table view - as said I am not sure exactly what you need.

Comment: because I want it to look like an entry in the tableview.. and because the data going in is dynamic and is being used to create the sections and rows the only other way I can think to do this is to insert into the begining of my dictionary.. But I dont think I can even do that.

Comment: in your last like where you say the line will scroll away thats exactly what I want. It just needs to be at the beginning. Basicly I have a tableview of entries and if the user wants to select all thats what this button will be for.

Comment: I would suggest then that you just redesign your UI so that you have an input area ABOVE the table with an OK button. When pressing OK the text the user just provided will go whereever it needs to. You can use [table reloadData] and your table view will be up to date once you inserted the text provided by the user into your data structures underlying the table

Comment: so all you need is a button like behaviour in your very first line in the very first section - and this is to select all? While this is certainly possible with the approach I described adding the "==0" check. I would now even recommend more that you consider redesigning the UI - why not just adding a button - always visible, which selects all lines (don't understand why it should not be visible once you scroll down the table) - this is certainly more iPhone like behaviour.

Comment: okay, thanks for the help, I guess I will just do that.. it will save alot of issues.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to customize your tableview section's header...
For example you can use something like this:

```
YourController.h
-(UIView *)headerView;

YourController.m
-(UIView *)headerView
{
    UIView *header = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    // Place everything you want in your header
    // using [header addSubview:yourSubview];
    // Finally set header's frame and return it
    header.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 44.0);
    return header;
}

// Use this to return header's height
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section == yourSection)
    {
        return [self headerView].frame.size.height;
    }
    else
    {
        return [self sectionHeaderHeight];
    }
}

// Use this to return your view
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableVIew *)tableVIew viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section == yourSection)  // To show the header only on a specified section
    {
        return [self headerView];
    }
    else
    {
        return nil;
    }
}
```

If you change your mind and want to customize below the tableView, your can use the same method changing Header with Footer.
Finally take a look at docs about these methods:
[- tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView%3aviewForHeaderInSection%3a)
[- tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView%3aheightForHeaderInSection%3a)
[- tableView:viewForFooterInSection:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView%3aviewForFooterInSection%3a)
[- tableView:heightForFooterInSection:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView%3aheightForFooterInSection%3a)

Hope this fits your needs!

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your response however I already have a section header for each section (alphabetical sections)... so I think I am going to have to go with the button like cell thats below the navigationbar but above the tableview.. so the tableview is able to scroll under it.. and the cell stay at the top.